# How to create a H2O cluster on google cloud with static external IP?

Tags: r, gcloud, h2o

Creating a new H2O-3 Cluster deployment in google cloud gives only 2 options for reserving an IP address: Ephemeral and None. Is it possible to create a h2o cluster with a static IP address. Using the "addresses" command in gcloud like:

```
gcloud compute addresses create h2oflow --addresses /* ephemeral external IP assigned to h2o cluster */
```

assigns the h2oflow address to only 1 of the nodes in the cluster. 
Is it possible to assign a static IP to an entire cluster of h2o nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The short answer is**: This is not offered as part of the Marketplace offering out of the box, but can be addressed along with the next release version.

**The long answer is**: technically yes. You'd need to follow the steps documented in Google Cloud Docs https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address, to reserve a static ip and then assign it to a vm. If you are creating a cluster manually, you'd start up N virtual machines, install the required software (e.g. java, python, h2o, h2o-depedencies, etc). Assign the static IP address to each of the VM's and then use the internal ips for clustering based on the flatfile. Theoretically, this should also be doable with the marketplace offering as well, where everything has already been preconfigured and flatfile.txt is generated with the internal ips. Just need to assign a static ip to the VM's

Comment: Thank you.actually,this question was raised because once h2o.shutdown() is called, the ephemeral ip is lost.So doing h20.init() did not work.We found from one of the answers in h2o forums that restarting the individual vms from the google console helps get a new ip assigned again.